# Using dots or colons in CSS effects

Tags: css

I'm working with css, so I don't know when to use dots and when to use colons for CSS efects, such as hover, active, visited. For example:

For list item named "tab", this code works:

```
.tab a.active
{ 
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #fff; 
}
```

When I use colon, effect doesn't apply:

```
.tab a:active 
{ 
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #fff; 
}
```

In the previous work, I use hover effect on ID element:

```
a:hover
{ 
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

This code worked. Is there a difference in these two effects, because in the first example, it is applied on class, and in the last example it is applied on ID?

Comment: [A complete list of selectors in the Selectors Level 3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

Answer (score 3):

`.class` this is a class

`#id` this is an id

`:after` this is a pseudoelement

For example: `#wrapper .button:hover` means that you have your mouse over an element like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="button">I'm a button</div> <!-- Mouse over this one -->
</div>
```

Let me know if it's useful.

Comment: PS. your `.tab a:active` code should work, supponsing that there is an `a` element inside an element with the class `tab`

Answer (score 2):

dot is used to give styles to a class and colon is used for any effect to pseudoelement (that is an element in a id or class).